# Can you curl files from GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to download a file from GitLab using the API?  I am using CentOS 6 commandline.  The documentation for the API says "Get file from repository" but it is only to get the metadata and not the file itself. The example they give is:

```
curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/test%2Epy/raw?ref=master'
```

If I use the raw option, it gives me the contents of the file, but it saves the name with as `test%2Epy/raw?ref=master`

How do I get it to save as `test.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `> test.py` to `curl` as below:

```
curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: ' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/test%2Epy/raw?ref=master' > test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use the group and project name instead of the project-id:

```
  response=$(curl "$GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/<group>%2F<project>/repository/files/<folder>%2Ftest%2E.py/raw?ref=master" \
    --silent \
    -o "test.py" \
    --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN")

  if  [[ $response == 4* ]] || [[ $response == 5* ]]; then
    echo ERROR - Http status: "$response"
    exit 1
  fi
```

It's important to URL encode the group + project path and the file path as well.